# How to use match in dplyr to order a column based on an external vector?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe, df:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("b2","d2","a1","c1"), b = c(12, 3, 54, 4))
> df
   a  b
1 b2 12
2 d2  3
3 a1 54
4 c1  4
```

And an external vector, that I would like the order of `a` to match:

```
vec <- c("a1","b2","c1","d2")
```

Normally I can do this as follows using `match`:

```
df <- df[match(vec, df$a),]

> df
   a  b
3 a1 54
1 b2 12
4 c1  4
2 d2  3
```

However, I would like to know if there is a way to do this in dplyr.  I have tried the following, but it did not work:

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(
        a = match(vec, a)
    )
> df
  a  b
1 3 12
2 1  3
3 4 54
4 2  4
```

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t use `mutate` here because you want to modify the entire data.frame, not just a single column.

Instead, as of ‘dplyr’ v1.0.0, you can use `summarize` here:

```
df <- df %>% summarize(.[match(vec, a), ])
```

In this expression, `.` stands in for the entire data.frame.

Comment: @Onyambu Why can’t `summarize` be used with duplicate values in `a` (besides discarding the duplicate value in `b`, but OP’s base R code does the same)?

Comment: Try using `df1 <- data.frame(a = df$a, b=1:8)` and see what happens

Comment: @Onyambu My code gives the same result as OP’s for your `df1`, since `match` doesn’t recycle the values of the first vector.

Answer (score 5):

You are only ordering in baseR, so equivalent `dplyr` syntax will be.  Moreover, you'll have to reverse the arguments of `match` because here we want to have an index of column of df into the vector `vec`

```
df %>% arrange(match(a, vec))
   a  b
1 a1 54
2 b2 12
3 c1  4
4 d2  3
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
df %>%
  arrange(ordered(a, vec))

   a  b
1 a1 54
2 b2 12
3 c1  4
4 d2  3
```

Comment: This is a great solution (better than mine!) if `vec` is a permutation of `a` but it fails if is a subset of `a`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ahy would `vec` be a subset? Then how exactly should the ones not in vec be ordered? That creates other difficulties

Comment: This is the way to go I think! You can actually simplify it even further to `df %>% arrange(ordered(a, vec))`